# Can someone please merge the 3 "free book" questions, or close 2?

Tags: support, status-completed

There are (at least) 3 good questions on "free books" available on the web:

- [List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812)  (asked Oct 11 '08, 119 answers)
- [What are some good free programming books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391523/what-are-some-good-free-programming-books)  (asked Dec 24 '08, 98 answers)
- [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873)  (asked Aug 22 '08, 50 answers)

Every time I come across a good book and I'd like to add it, but I'm not sure to which thread..

Comment: The second one was actually merged with yet another last June, but that was when merges were still awful.

Comment: I merged the second one into the first.  The third one is about good books on programming languages in general, not specifically free ebooks.  I don't want to pollute the free ebook question with a bunch of paper book answers, so I think they should stay separate.

Comment: @Bill the lizard, the problem I have with merging is that the one with the answers in the question (isn't that against SO convention?) duplicates a lot of the answers in the upvoted answer.  I think I'll go through and move all the answers to the answer so they're all in one place. What say you?

Comment: @George: I agree, it is better to have the master list in the answers rather than the question.

Comment: I thought merging left stubs now; what happened to  #391523?

Comment: @Shog9: I'm being taken to the stub when I click the link for that one (2nd link in the list above).  Are you getting the "page not found" message, or are you being automatically forwarded to #194812?

Comment: @Bill: I see the stub now - when I commented, I was getting "page not found".

Answer (score 2):

Since the 'answers' in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812) were against SO convention and they heavily duplicated the list in the answer, I merged them [with the answers from my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926) and removed all duplicates.